# Drupal 8 guest user access to node

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In drupal 8, how can I make a node available only to unlogged user and not available to logged users. In other words how can I make a node available only to guest users ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Straightforward steps:

1. Go to /admin/people/permissions
2. Search "View published content" and allow the access of node to whom you would like to be.

Refer image[image]